# inserting into relational table from entity table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

Hi I want to create a trigger which will insert values on relational table A_EQ, A_U and A_P after inserting the values to entity table ACCOUNTS. The values will the inserted into A_EQ if only  the ACCOUNTS.TYPE='Equipments', into A_U if only ACCOUNTS.TYPE='Utility' and into A_P for the rest.
Whenever I'm trying to compile the trigger certain errors are showing:

```
Error(40,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_U'
Error(41,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_U'
Error(42,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_U'
Error(45,9): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_EQ'
Error(46,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_EQ'
Error(47,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_EQ'
Error(50,9): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_P'
Error(51,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_P'
Error(52,13): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.A_P'
Error(57,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if
```

The Code for trigger is given below:

```
create or replace trigger accounts_relational_insert
 after insert   on accounts

REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS Old


for each row 
declare
sys_month VARCHAR2 (10) ;
i_month VARCHAR2 (10);
old1 int;
curr_amount number (20,2);
curr_id varchar2 (20);
curr_txn varchar2 (20);
curr_type varchar2 (20);
begin
select to_char(SYSDATE,'Month')  into sys_month from dual;
select ACCOUNTS_ID_SEQ.currval into old1 from dual;
select to_char(paid_on,'Month') into i_month from accounts where  transaction_id ='Txn' || lpad(old1,9,'0');
select amount  into curr_amount from accounts where transaction_id='Txn' || lpad(old1,9,'0');
select  id into curr_id from accounts where transaction_id='Txn' || lpad(old1,9,'0');
select transaction_id into curr_txn from accounts where transaction_id='Txn' || lpad(old1,9,'0');
select type into curr_type from accounts where transaction_id='Txn' || lpad(old1,9,'0');
if i_month = sys_month then
    if curr_type ='Utility' then 
            :new.a_u.transaction_id := curr_txn;
            :new.a_u.u_id :=curr_id;
            :new.a_u.amount := curr_amount;
            
    else if curr_type='Equipments' then
        :new.a_eq.transaction_id := curr_txn;
            :new.a_eq.eq_id :=curr_id;
            :new.a_eq.amount := curr_amount;
     else
     
        :new.a_p.transaction_id := curr_txn;
            :new.a_p.barcode:=curr_id;
            :new.a_p.amount := curr_amount;
            
    end if;
end if;

end;
```

The Tables are given below:

[image: ACCOUNTS]
[image: A_EQ]
[image: A_U]
[image: A_P]

It will be very helpful if someone tells me how to resolve this error and also if there is any other way to insert into relational tables after inserting on accounts table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange the trigger simply as simple as this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER accounts_relational_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON accounts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_CHAR(:new.paid_on, 'YYYYMM') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMM') THEN
    IF    :new.type = 'Utility' THEN
      INSERT INTO a_u VALUES(:new.id, :new.transaction_id, :new.amount);
    ELSIF :new.type = 'Equipments' THEN
      INSERT INTO a_eq VALUES(:new.id, :new.transaction_id, :new.amount);    
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO a_p VALUES(:new.id, :new.transaction_id, :new.amount);
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

where

- the values, which are already been able to get from identifiers of
  columns of the table `accounts` qualified with `:new` , to be
  inserted shouldn't return from `SELECT` statements. Moreover, you would get mutating
  trigger error for this case.
- indeed, defining the local variables are not needed due to the fact
  that expressed above, and also values for `i_month` and `sys_month`
  will directly be derived from `TO_CHAR(:new.paid_on, 'YYYYMM')` and
  `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYMM')` respectively. Btw, do not prefer using string
  expression within character conversion such as `Month`, since you might not
  only face case sensitivity issues, but also might fail for international
  studies related to language differences.
- the trigger is created on `accounts` table, for the other tables you
  should use `INSERT` statements, cannot use such variable assignments.
- The expression `REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old` is redundant, as
  being default.